# How to write CD-Text with brasero or k3b

Tags: cd, burning, brasero, k3b

I'm on to produce an audio CD and I have here the master-CD (produced on another UBUNTU system) which will be sent to the manufacturer. Before I want to make a copy.

There is CD-Text on the CD and none of my approaches in copying the CD-Text also was successful. I tried disk to disk copy with Brasero. Raw-mode copy with k3b. And I tried to write from the bin and cuesheet (the CD-Text is in there!) and it's working all flawless, no problems with the audio, but without writing the CD-Text.

Any idea how to get this done?

Is it possible that this is a hardware issue concerning my dvd burner?

Comment: Didn't try, but this may help: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/cdrdao.1.html

Comment: Brasero is just a graphical interface, I think it's using cdrdao. It also creates a TOC file and in the TOC file the CD-Text is there. But it won't write in on to the CD.